# Should the [read] tag be removed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

I just looked at the [read](/questions/tagged/read) tag, and the question seem to vary among reading binary data (from somewhere), reading text, reading files, and other unrelated things. There's only 6 subscribers and no tag wiki, along with a small count of questions.

What should be done with the tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Agreed, both [read](/questions/tagged/read) and [write](/questions/tagged/write) are now burninated.

Only two questions were left untagged (may be referring to deleted questions), which indicates to me that these tags were 99.99% superfluous.

[image: tag burninated]

Answer (score 3):

Kill it! It's not helpful at all, and it could mean almost anything, as you say, depending on the context. I'm starting removal now :)

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 3):

In that token, wouldn't [write](/questions/tagged/write) also make a decent candidate for burnination too?  They're both I/O operations, and [io](/questions/tagged/io) could handle both cases neatly.

(And yes, I'm all for cleaning out [read](/questions/tagged/read).)